# It is known that the equation $ax + (b - 3)= (5a - 1)x+3b$ has more than one solution. Find the value of $100a + 4b$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, systems-of-equations

> It is known that the equation $ax + (b - 3)= (5a - 1)x+3b$ has more than one solution. Find the value of $100a + 4b$.

Comment: Is it an equation in $x$?

Comment: Sorry it's 100a + 4b

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my exercise, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us help you, and [help yourself as well](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26702). You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  the only way this can happen is if the coefficient of $x$ is $0$.  Then $x$ can have any value you want.  This tells you what $a$ is.  Now remove the term because it is zero and you have an equation in $b$.  Solve it.

Added:  you rearrange it to $(4a-1)x=-2b-3$  This gives $a=\frac 14$.  Now if $b=-\frac 32$ the equation is satisfied whatever the value of $x$.  We then evaluate $100+4b$ to get $94$

Comment: But how do you get the value of a

Comment: Is the final answer 19

Comment: @JohnTom, it is.